# How to display a set of custom contents in Taxonomy URL?

Tags: 8, commerce, taxonomy-terms

I am working with Drupal Commerce using core Drupal 8 and the type of data I am using is Product. When I tag a product with a taxonomy term and visit page for that taxonomy term, I don't see anything. On the other hand, when I tag article with a taxonomy term, I can see all the articles tagged when I visit page for that tag. What influences behavior of taxonomy term and how can I manipulate it to display products?

I believe that it only works with a content type and product is not a content type. In older version of Drupal Commerce there was a product display content type which had Product as reference. That is no longer the case, now product can't be used as reference.

**Edit:** Product can still be used as reference. You can use it as reference to create something similar to  Product Display in older version of Drupal Commerce Kickstart

Comment: In D8 those taxonomy term pages are just a view which is geared up for content entities. You'll probably need to create a new view that uses product entities and either add a block onto that page or replace that whole view page if you're not needing it for content

Comment: Thanks, I decided to keep product inside content, which made everything much easier